# ISC DHCP Server - Matching client identifier won't work for single device

Tags: cisco, isc-dhcp

I hope someone can help me with this problem.

## What am I trying to do

I want to provide information to a Cisco ASR1k depending on its serial number.
Reason for this is I don't have any MAC address of the device. Only the serial number of the chassie is known.

Problematic device is running IOS-XE

I need to use ISC DHCP Server 4.4

### What have I tried

Since I already did this with another Cisco device (another model with IOS-XR running on it) I just copied my config and replaced the given serial number.

**Working config**

```
class "working-cisco-device" {
    match if (substring(option dhcp-client-identifier,0,11) = "SERIALWORKING");
    option routers 1.1.1.1;
    filename="http://SERVER/pub/configs/cisco/SERIALWORKING.txt";

subnet 10.119.168.128 netmask 255.255.255.128 {
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.128;
    log(info, option dhcp-client-identifier);
    pool {
      allow members of "working-cisco-device";
      allow members of "not-working-cisco-device";
      range 10.119.168.131 10.119.168.140;
    }
}
}
```

This device boots up without a config, gets the correct information from the dhcp server and download its config from the FTP server.

**Configuration of problematic device**

```
class "not-working-cisco-device" {
    match if substring(option dhcp-client-identifier,0,11) = "SERIALNOTWORKING";
    #match if option host-name ~~ "Router";
    option routers 1.1.1.1;
    option bootfile-name "http://SERVER/pub/configs/cisco/SERIALNOTWORKING.txt";

subnet 10.119.168.128 netmask 255.255.255.128 {
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.128;
    pool {
      allow members of "working-cisco-device";
      allow members of "not-working-cisco-device";
      range 10.119.168.131 10.119.168.140;
    }
}
```

Boot up this device gives me this output:

**NOTE**: Since the length of option 61 if this device is 12 I already changed the substring indexes with no success.

I also tried to match against a regex with (this syntax worked for some other devices where I evaluated the vendor-class-identifier)

```
match if option dhcp-client-identifier ~~ ".*SERIALNOTWORKING.*";
```

To check if it works at all, I matched the devices hostname with

```
match if option host-name ~~ "Router";
```

Doing so works and the device started fetching its config.

```
Jun 10 07:24:36 m4bnvmvs0133 dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from f8:xx:xx:xx:4b:40 via 10.119.168.130: network 10.119.168.128/25: no free leases  
.
.
.
.                                                                         
Jun 10 07:24:40 m4bnvmvs0133 dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from f8:xx:xx:xx:4b:40 via 10.119.168.130: network 10.119.168.128/25: no free leases
```

**DHCP Discover messages**
[image: DHCP Discover dump]

As you can see the length of Option 61 is 11 on the working device and 12 on the not working device.

I feel like I have a basic implementation problem when it comes to evaluating the individual fields of the DHCP Discover message.

Thanks in advance and best regards

yabberth

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself.

```
class "now-working" {
    match if substring(option dhcp-client-identifier,1,12) = "SERIAL";
                                                     ^  ^
                                                     |  |
                                                    changed
    
    option routers 10.119.168.129;
    option bootfile-name "http://SERVER/pub/configs/cisco/SERIAL.txt";
}

subnet 10.119.168.128 netmask 255.255.255.128 {
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.128;
    log(info, substring(option dhcp-client-identifier,1,12));
    pool {
      allow members of "now-working";
      range 10.119.168.131 10.119.168.140;
    }
}
```

**NOTE**
The log() function is very useful.
I only increased the last index within the substring() function call.
I haven't realized that the dhcp-client-identifier has a type defined. So we need to count from the second byte not from the first one.

[image]

**Logging Output**

```
Jun 10 10:16:14 dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx via 10.119.168.130
Jun 10 10:16:15 dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 10.119.168.138 to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (Router) via 10.119.168.130
Jun 10 10:16:15 dhcpd: SERIALNUMBER
Jun 10 10:16:15 dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 10.119.168.138 (172.22.134.147) from f8:0f:6f:21:4b:40 (Router) via 10.119.168.130
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx dhcpd: DHCPACK on 10.119.168.138 to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (Router) via 10.119.168.130
```

I'm still not sure, why the regex matching didn't work. But I can live with this solution.

Comment: This is really great information, what format does the http://SERVER/pub/configs/cisco/SERIAL.txt does it accept? is it serial,ip?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Haven"t seen it. 

In this file the configuration of the device is present. It is just plain text

e.G

cat serial.txt 
!! IOS XR
hostname fancyDevice
username root
 group root-lr
 
 secret 10 $1212$fdsf4k59be
!
interface MgmtEth0/RSP0/CPU0/0
 description Management
 vrf Management
 ipv4 address 172.19.87.57/27
 no shutdown
!